# Not answering solves the equation even though I know there is an answer

Tags: matlab

```
clear all
close all
clc
gam=1.4
cp=1004
M=.0289645
R=8.314
sv=@(t)sqrt(gam.*R.*t./M)
m1=input('enter m1:')
p1=input('enter p1:')
t1=input('enter t1:')
l=input('enter l:')
d=input('enter d:')
f=input('enter f:')
lstar=d/(4*f)*(-1/(gam*1^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(1^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*1^2)))-(-1/(gam*m1^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(m1^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*m1^2)))))
syms m2
a=d/(4*f)*(-1/(gam*m2^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(m2^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*m2^2)))-(-1/(gam*m1^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(m1^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*m1^2)))))==l
z=solve(a,m2)
```

In this code, by entering the values ​​m1: .3, p1: 1, t1: 273, l: 30, d: .15 ,f: .005, the answer should be about m2= .475, but I get this error   >>> Warning: Unable to find explicit solution. For options, see help.

> In sym/solve (line 317)
> In b (line 17)

Comment: I don’t see `sv` or `lstar` being used. Are these extraneous to the question and only there to waste my time, or am I missing where they are used?

Comment: sv is just a function that is used in another script but lstar is a variable that shoulde be calculated.

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. Having irrelevant statements in your code makes it harder for people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Abbas:

I recognize that you're automating the fanno flow relations in your script. In this particular instance, you're solving for the subsonic unchoked case. I copied and modified the last three lines of your script as follows:

```
syms m2 gam m1 d f l
a=d/(4*f)*(-1/(gam*m2^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(m2^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*m2^2)))-(-1/(gam*m1^2)-(gam+1)/(2*gam)*log(m1^2/((1+(gam-1)/2*m1^2)))))==l;
latex(a)
```

Essentially, I turned all variables into `syms` objects. The `latex` command is a handy function wich interprets symbolic equations and generates the appropriate LateX syntax for typesetting purposes. I use this output to render the equation as you've typed it (using MATLAB's publishing feature)  and this is what I get:
[image]
The equation above is incorrect for the aerodynamics problem that you're solving. Revisit the equation using your aerodynamics textbook and verify that your symbolic equation `a` is incorrect. Using the following script I obtain the answer you gave for m2:

```
gam=1.4; %Ratio of specific heats.
m1 = 0.3; %Upstream Mach Number
l = 30; %Pipe Length
d = 0.15; %Pipe diameter
f = 0.005; %Friction factor
syms m2 
L1 = (1-m1^2)/(gam*(m1^2)) + (gam+1)*log(0.5*(gam+1)*(m1^2)/(1+(gam-1)*(m1^2)/2))/(2*gam); 
L2 = (1-m2^2)/(gam*(m2^2)) + (gam+1)*log(0.5*(gam+1)*(m2^2)/(1+(gam-1)*(m2^2)/2))/(2*gam);
eq = d*(L1-L2)/(4*f) - l;
vpasolve(eq,m2,0.2)
```

Lessons

- Notice that your `a` symbolic expression is very long and hard to read. I believe what got you was this "unreadability." Breaking up a long equation into sub `syms` objects helps with readability. To further help with readability, refer back to the `latex` function and the publishing technique strategy.
- You used the `solve` function as opposed to the `vpasolve`. The former attempts to algebraically solve for the variable you specified (in this case `m2`). Sometimes, however, because of transcendental functions (like the fanno flow relations), this is simply not possible (hence the error). Regardless, the use of `solve` is unwarranted, what you seek is a numeric value. `vpasolve` on the other hand will numerically find the roots to the symbolic expressions you input.
- In my callout to `vpasolve` there is a `0.2` argument. Sometimes, MATLAB's default root-finding algorithms fail to converge upon roots. If this is the case, you can use an optional parameter to specify an initial guess that is close enough to the solution that the algorithm will find the root. Think of it as "lending a hand" to `vpasolve`. In my case, the absence of an initial guess made `vpasolve` return an empty array, without a reasonable initial guess it wouldn't converge to the correct answer.